# How to set text but keeping value in ASPxClientCombobox

Tags: client, devexpress

For example:

Text = "Select" and Value = null

```
cbbFrequentadorClient.SetText('Select');
cbbFrequentadorClient.SetValue(null);
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified that `EnableClientSideAPI` is set to `True`?

Comment: If you're trying to set the text but keep the current value of the selected item, can you just add a new item to the list with your text and a copy of the current value? Or does that not fit with what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add item to combo in client code you need to use [ASPxClientComboBox.AddItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBox_AddItemtopic) method. However, if you set value to null and text to some value (e.g. Select) combo value will be set to that text, not null. 
In order to achieve your goal you need to add blank item in server side code.
You can use this code if your combo isn't bind to datasource:

```html
<dxe:ASPxComboBox runat="server" ID="cmb1" ClientInstanceName="cmb1"/>
```

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        cmb1.Items.Add("Select", null);
        cmb1.Items.Add("One", 1);
        cmb1.Items.Add("Two", 2);
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
cmb1.SetSelectedIndex(0);
```

to set combo value to null.

If you have combo bound to datasource you should add null item in combo DataBound event handler:

```cs
Items.Insert(0, new ListEditItem("Select", null));
```

Also, take a look at this [suggestion](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S130374.aspx) (you can upvote it).